# Angular rambda dealing with readonly types returned from immutable array operations

Tags: angular, typescript, rambda.js

I'm having a problem using [rambda](https://github.com/selfrefactor/rambda) (a typescript compatible ramda clone) using their functional utility functions for selectors. Rambda enforces immutability by setting readonly return and input types to their utility functions.

I'm looking for suggestions about getting around changing the codebase to use the immutable readonly arrays.

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rambda-readonly-issue) if you need it.

- [/app/courses/reducers/courses.reducer.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rambda-readonly-issue?file=src/app/courses/reducers/courses.reducer.ts)
- [/app/courses/components/course-list/course-list.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rambda-readonly-issue?file=src/app/courses/components/course-list/course-list.component.ts)

eg. Rambda's typescript definition file uses.

```js
export function filter<T>(predicate: Predicate<T>): (input: readonly T[]) => readonly T[];
```

Using standard imperative code wouldn't require the interface to be readonly

```js
const selectFoos = createSelector(
  selectAllFoos,
  foos => foos.filter(R.identity)
)
// => Selector<object, Foo>
```

If I use `R.filter` in my selector the return type is `readonly: T[]`

```js
const selectFoos = createSelector(
  selectAllFoos,
  R.filter<Foo>(R.identity), // becomes `readonly Foo[]`
)
// => Selector<object, readonly Foo[]>
```

Changing the type where I consume the selected observable does get around the type error, but is there any better way to deal with it?

I would like to use rambda for my new job, but don't think it's a good idea at the start to change all their code to readonly to suit rambda, and I'm not sure what will happen if I then pipe that value into something else that I don't control that won't accept readonly interfaces.

```
@Component({ ... })
class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  /* without the readonly property there is a type error */
  // $foos: Observable<Foo[]>

  /* readonly property added to interface */
  $foos: Observable<readonly Foo[]>

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.foos$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectFoos))
  }
}
```

Cheers for any help.

Comment: I'm curious if you've tried simply using Ramda instead of Rambda.  (Note: Ramda author here, so may be biased, and I've never used Rambda.)  Ramda does not modify your data but it doesn't try to insist that you avoid doing so as well.  There are occasional Ramda/TS glitches, but they're fairly rare, from what I hear.

Comment: I like that rambda is tree shakeable, slimmer and faster, ramda has a much larger footprint and at the time I was learning functional programming with typescript there was no typescript definition file. I should probably take another look

Comment: Ramda is also tree-shakeable now.  It is definitely not as slim, still supporting old versions of JS.  I don't know anything about the speed.  I'm not here to push Ramda, and if Rambda has continued to make improvements since I last saw it, it might well be worth considering.  But there is a clear difference in philosophy, and it looks as though immutability might be part of that.

Comment: Rambda is full of readonly because of th usage of ESLint immutable plugin. This question will be discussed further in the Github issue - https://github.com/selfrefactor/rambda/issues/565